# gradle not excuting task to copy files

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using following code in `build.gradle` that copies different configuration files for airship. However what I am finding is my tasks `copyReleaseConfigFileTask`/`copyDebugConfigFileTask` are not being called. Can anyone give hints as to why the tasks I have defined below are not getting executed?

```
task copyReleaseConfigFileTask(type: Copy) << {
    println "-> using airship release config"
    from 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties.release'
    into 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties'
}

task copyDebugConfigFileTask(type: Copy) << {
    println "-> using airship debug config"
    from 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties.debug'
    into 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties'
}

assembleDebug {
    dependsOn copyDebugConfigFileTask
}

assembleRelease {
    dependsOn copyReleaseConfigFileTask
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't properly configured your tasks. You've tried to make CopySpecification configuration in the execution phase, though it has to be done at configuration phase. To achieve this, you have to delete `<<` from your task specification. It has to be rewritten this way:

```
task copyReleaseConfigFileTask(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
         println "-> using airship release config"
    }
    from 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties.release'
    into 'app/src/main/assets'
    rename('airshipconfig.properies.release','airshipconfig.properties')
}

task copyDebugConfigFileTask(type: Copy) {
    doLast {
        println "-> using airship debug config"
    }
    from 'app/src/main/assets/airshipconfig.properties.debug'
    into 'app/src/main/assets'
    rename('airshipconfig.properties.debug','airshipconfig.properties')
}
```

Note, `<<` is the same as a `doLast` closure. So, this will properly configure your copy tasks, but the message will appear only after execution.

One more, you've provided an `into` value as path with file name, but it has to be a path to the directory, not a file. To rename it, use a `rename` closure additionally. Read about it in the official [CopySpec API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html)

Comment: If do the change you suggested, my tasks doesn't get executed at all. I don't see the message , and no files get copied.

Comment: Is your task on execution graph? I mean, how do you make it running? Do you call `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease`? Do this tasks are presented in the logs output?

Comment: I invoked gradle as ./gradlew assembleDebug , FWIW I am using gradle 2.10. Are you asking if I see app:copyDebugConfigFileTask or :app:copyReleaseConfigFileTask in configuration phase, answer to that is yes. I do see ':app:copyDebugConfigFileTask UP-TO-DATE'

Comment: If it says it's up-to-date, then it means, that nothing will be done at the execution phase, since Gradle doesn't see any difference between previewsly runned build and now. That may be caused by the fact, nothing changed in this files or the paths are wrong. You can run your build with --rerun-tasks flag to prevent any task optimisation. Then your task will be executed anyway.

Comment: Furthermore, into use to be a folder, but you made it a file. If you have to rename your file during the copy process, then use a rename closure

Comment: I used above snippet you posted , verified that files that I am copying do exists so there is no issue with files not existing. Even with that when I run gradle with --debug option I see following message 12:16:45.331 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':app:copyDebugConfigFileTask' as it has no source files. So gradel looking at wrong place or I am setting up something wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115149/discussion-between-subodh-nijsure-and-stanislav).